# Best way to store date and month only in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

So I have to store a particular date of the year, any year. So I will only be needing the date and month part of a date.

I can either store it with any year and just ignore it on the programming side but that feels dirty. Any better way to handle this?

Closest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574390/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-only-month-day-and-time-in-database-table) one but that includes time component as well and goes on some different tangent.

Comment: A `month` and a `day` column?

Comment: So two columns? That seems unnecessary, why have two when I will always need them together.

Comment: IMO that is clean. But you could also do `1231` - put it in one INT field called `month_day`

Comment: Then I'll have to deal with padding zeros and stuff because 111 can mean anything.

Comment: INT field, so `1201` would be 1st of dec. But I would use 2 fields. I voted to close since this is clearly opinion-based

Comment: Yeah but I'll have to add zeros manually. In my logic I would have two numbers 12 and 1. So I'll have to make it 01. Otherwise 111 is ambiguous, it could be 11 Jan or 1 Nov.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I would use 2 fields ;-)

Comment: Use a date field and for year put 0000.   `0000-12-01` is December 1st every year

Comment: @HankyPanky that actually looks neat. Thanks! If you add that I'll accept it.

Comment: Please note that to have year zero in dates you need to lower the SQL_MODE settings (thus allowing other integrity errors leak in). The mode to fine tune this behaviour,  NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, has just been deprecated BTW.

Comment: That sucks big time.

Comment: I inadvertently removed a previous comment while trying to edit it. I was basically saying that in a similar use case (month and year) I normally use two numeric columns, although MySQL makes it hard to enforce valid values (e.g. month between 1 and 12). Not sure why you think that having two columns (or four) is messy—messy is having 30 column tables (which I've actually seen).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález That looked messy to me because that complicates otherwise simple things like sorting, grouping, WHERE clauses, etc. I'll have to CONCAT everywhere to bring two columns together to do anything meaningful with them. 0000-xx-xx makes all that so much easier.

Comment: CONCAT to sort or filter? Why not just `ORDER BY month, day`? (Which, by the way, is as easy or difficult as `ORDER BY month_day`.) Whatever, you know your needs and likes. If you prefer a single text column, just go for it. It should work fine it properly indexed and validated.

Comment: CONCAT was for pulling data out. ORDER is trivial yes.

Comment: @Martin I need the day and month, I need to do away with the year.

Comment: @Achshar sorry my confusion. I gave an answer below

Comment: @Achshar what are you going to use this data for? That can help determine the best way to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL >= 5.7.6, you could use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). A trivial example table would look like this (untested as, ironically, I don't have access to a recent MySQL server right now):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    the_date DATE,
    month_date VARCHAR(5) AS CONCAT(MONTH(the_date), '-', DAY(the_date))
);
```

Of course, change the generated value according to your needs (different separator, padding with zeroes on the month, etc.)

If you're stuck with an older version, you could perform a similar conversion using a view.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with just having a `DATE` column value, in this example called `my_date` :

```
SELECT MONTH(my_date) AS myMonth, DAY(my_date) AS myDay, <othercolumns> 
FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

Then you can use your PHP to get your row and output `$row['myMonth']`, etc.

You can also output the MONTH / DAY values as any format string you like using MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) .

You can also `CONCAT` these two values if you need them in a single column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(my_date),' ',DAY(my_date)) as month_day, <othercolumns> 
FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

### Warning:

Storing dates as `0000-00-00` is perfectly valid but MySQL year 0000 is *not a leap year* so you can not store 0000-02-29, this will instead be saved as a default `0000-00-00`.

You might as well use a default year value that is leap year safe (such as year 2k) if you're sure you're never going to use the year value. such as (`2000-XX-XX`).

Comment: Thanks for the warning of 0000-02-29! 0004-02-29 would be the smallest possible year.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the [Julian Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) as an integer, and [convert](https://www.dm.usda.gov/procurement/toolkit/docs/calendar.pdf) to Georgian Month/Day when you need it. This can keep things quite clean. Keep your eyes peeled for the leap year.

The notion of Julian here is truly, just "Day of year" and [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735528/php-how-to-go-from-day-of-the-year-to-date-and-vice-versa) when needed.

```
function getDateFromDay($dayOfYear, $year) {
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', strval($dayOfYear) . ' ' . strval($year));
  return $date;
}
```

Comment: Woha, that's like opening a whole different can of worms. Leap years thing sounds simple enough until you get to the multiple of 400 rule. Lol.

Comment: With php, using their DateTime module, one shouldn't really have to worry about it. Though, the basis here really depends upon what you are using the day/month for, and what calculations you are going to do with them.

Comment: It's basically a start and end date of the plans that users can subscribe to. The plans describe dates for any year and are annual.

Comment: This seems like the best course of action would be a subscription start date, and a subscription end date, and when they renew the subscription, then the end-date gets pushed a year out. At least, that's how I've handled subscriptions in the past.

Comment: This isn't for any particular user, this is the main index table, so this is used as foreign keys for user's invoices.The concept of year doesn't exist in this table

Comment: So you're talking about having a table that just holds id, monthday and a given invoice has the monthday_id FK reference? I'm not sure what the benefit of this would be.

Comment: It's useful because I don't want to store start/end date of plans for every subscription which can be hundreds of thousands.